# Resistors in parallel - finding total current

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance

[image]

I am given this circuit, where $R_1 = 4.00 \Omega$, $R_2=8.00 \Omega$, and $R_3 =5.00\Omega$. I was given by the problem statement that $I_2$, the current through $R_2$ is $I_2=4\text{A}$. I found the current through $R_1$ to be $I_1 = 8 \text{A}$. I used the relation $\frac{I_1}{I_2} = \frac{R_2}{R_1}$ to solve for $I_1$.

The next part of the problem asks us to find the current $I_3$ through $R_3$. Here is what I tried to do:

I considered the part of $R_1$ and $R_2$ as one combined parallel component to $R_3$. Since $R_1$ and $R_2$ are parallel (WRT each other), I did $\frac{1}{R_{eq}} = \frac{1}{R_1}+\frac{1}{R_2}$. Then I summed their currents, $I_{eq} = I_1 + I_2$.

*I am not sure if that last step where I summed their currents is legal.*

Is the right idea to treat the $R_1$ and $R_2$ parts as one component parallel to $R_3$? I wanted to use the relation $\frac{I_{eq}}{I_3}=\frac{R_3}{R_{eq}}$, where $I_{eq}$ and $R_{eq}$ denote the whole $R_1$ and $R_2$ component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, what you did is correct. You have rediscovered [Kirchoff's current law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff%27s_current_law).

[image: Nodal analysis]

Consider the point I've marked with the red circle where the wires from R₁ and R₂ meet. The current flowing into this point has to be the same as the current flowing out of that point, and that means:

$$ I_1 + I_2 = I_3 $$

Analysing a circuit by looking at the *nodes*, i.e. the points where wires join, is known as [nodal analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nodal_analysis) and it's an important part of your toolbox.